# Can I remove WooCommerce specific product categories from shop managers?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, user-roles, capabilities

Can I remove WooCommerce specific product categories from shop managers, so that they can publish products only in some specific categories.

I tried this, but it's not working.

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
if (!current_user_can('activate_plugins')) {
  add_action('wp_head', 'removeCategories', 100);
  function removeCategories()
  {
    echo "<style>#product_cat-23{display: none !important;}</style>";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
if (!current_user_can('activate_plugins')) {
  add_action('admin_head', 'removeCategories', 100);
  function removeCategories()
  {
    echo "<style>#product_cat-23{display: none !important;}</style>";
  }
}
```

It's admin_head for admin UI.